# Having trouble reading lines from a file

Tags: c++, if-statement, file-io, while-loop, file-handling

I have a text file 'patient_info.txt' like this:

100 Pranabesh 12/12/2014 15/12/2014 Dr.Ajit_Mukherjee,Dr.Pramotesh_Halder AC02 Tuberculosis

101 Sampad 01/03/2014 07/03/2014 Dr.Sarbani_Ghosh GEN304,Dengue

102 Sambit 22/11/2014 NA Dr.Vashkar_Ganguly GEN310 Liver_Malfunction

I need to take each line as input and compare the first field.The trouble is my code doesn,t read the lines after the first line and it goes into an infinite loop.

Code goes like this:::

```
while(1)
            {
                cout<<"Enter patient Id to display the details:";
                cin>>id;
                while(1)
                {
                    r=fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %s %s %s",&patient_id,&name,&admit_date,&release_date,&doc_consulted,&details);
                    while( r != EOF)
                    {
                        cout<<name<<endl;
                        if( patient_id == id)
                        {
                            cout<<name<<" "<<doc_consulted<<endl;
                            found=1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            r=fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %s %s %s",&patient_id,&name,&admit_date,&release_date,&doc_consulted,&details);
                    }
                    if( !found)
                        cout<<"\nInvalid Patient Id...Enter again....\n\n";
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if(found)
                    break;
            }
```

I can't fix it.Please help....

Comment: I assume you meant to put `C++` in your title instead of `C`, right?

Comment: What's the type of name?

Comment: type of name is char*

Comment: This is a really gross mixture of C and C++. Stick to `cin`/`cout` and file streams. Look up `ifstream`.

Comment: if we do it in simple C, how should we do it?I am learning c++....

Comment: it really doesn't matter whether its c or c++ because most compilers like gcc and codeblock, dev-c++ etc. recognize c and c++. Though ifstream is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
r=fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %s %s %s",&patient_id,&name,&admit_date,&release_date,&doc_consulted,&details);
```

Should be:

```
r=fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %s %s %s", patient_id,name,admit_date,release_date,doc_consulted,details);
```

You don't need the `&` when reading into a string. Also `fgets(char *string, int num, FILE *stream)` might be more appropriate in this situation but its up to you how you would like to read line by line from the file.

One more thing, try using a debugger to step through your while loops. It might help to see what one iteration of your while loops return.

Comment: He's working in C++, not C. You should probably supply a C++ answer.